# Overview of typicals RAID/wear leveling algorithms used in SSD controllers

Tags: flash, controller, algorithm, wear-leveling

I am trying to understand SSD controller design. I am particularly interested in the physical distribution of data to several NAND chips/dies.

Can somebody point me towards an "idiot's guide to SSD engineering"? ;-)

Or alternatively a description of the RAID/wear leveling algorithms used in SSD controllers. Early ones (pre-TRIM) would be perfectly fine.

Comment: This sort of thing is likely to be a trade secret, although if you can find a datasheet for an SSD controller there might be info in there.

Comment: @pjc50 Clearly this is a trade secret. That being said, the algorithms are fairly well known (just not to me). In particular the data recovery community knows a fair bit about the specific implementations. I was hoping to find somebody here who happens to have worked in data recovery.

Comment: Please try to keep the questions "[reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)."

Comment: @PabloMaurin I am not asking for an answer that is book-scope. I wrote in my question "point me toward" to which one can answer with a link to the book. I do not understand why you think this is too wide in scope.

Comment: @Marvin I've been interested in this myself but haven't had the motivation to look. However, if I find said motivation, I would start with universities or open-source drivers.

Comment: @AnalogArsonist Open-source drivers will not be useful for understanding the RAID/wear leveling algorithms. This happens in the firmware which simulates a block device. Thus any "drivers" will be the same as for an ordinary hard drive. And of course the firmware is proprietary. - That being said, the knowledge is out there. I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you start with the [OpenSSD project](http://www.openssd-project.org/wiki/The_OpenSSD_Project).  It is GPL-licensed SSD firmware that can be used as a point of departure in your research. More info on the goals of the project [here](http://www.openssd-project.org/mediawiki/images/Kcc2011.pdf).

> The OpenSSD Project is an initiative to promote research and education
>   on the recent SSD (Solid State Drive) technology by providing easy
>   access to OpenSSD platforms on which open source SSD firmware can be
>   developed. Currently, we offer an OpenSSD platform based on the
>   commercially successful BarefootTM controller from Indilinx Co., Ltd.
>   This site is also intended to be a forum to share various simulators,
>   tools, and workload generators and traces related to SSDs, among
>   researchers in academia and industry.

Comment: Thank you! This helps tremendously - even if much of the documentation is in Korean. I would still love to hear if somebody knows other resources.

Answer (score 1):

My [2016 survey paper on Flash memory](https://www.academia.edu/12769873/A_Survey_of_Software_Techniques_for_Using_Non-Volatile_Memories_for_Storage_and_Main_Memory_Systems) (and other non-volatile memories) reviews many wear-leveling techniques and several other software techniques for managing flash-based SSDs. It also provides background on non-volatile memories, so it may be useful for a beginner.